# What did Auggie's father give to his wife in the movie Wonder?

Tags: plot-explanation, wonder

There is a scene roughly in the last third of *Wonder* where Auggie's parents Nate and Isabel (Owen Wilson and Julia Roberts) spend an evening together while the kids are out. Nate has a surprise gift for his wife. She opens the box just enough to see it, laughs, and closes it again. So I asked myself the question:

What's in the box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My wife and I wondered this too. According to [this Sydney Morning Herald article](https://www.smh.com.au/entertainment/movies/owen-wilson-loves-how-wonder-deals-with-tough-issues-20171117-gzn6p7.html) it was a different thing each time they shot the scene, and the audience isn't supposed to see it.

> Roberts opens the box, but it's filmed in such a way that the audience can't see what's inside. [...] "There were different things each time she opened it," Wilson says. "What got the biggest reaction had to do with a reference to something the director said at the lunch. That really got her."